# Ruby: What's the difference between IO and ARGV?

Tags: ruby, io, argv

I've been trying to understand the differences between the two, but as of now I have a very rudimentary understanding. ARGV is a subset of IO I believe.  I know that ARGV returns an array when called into a Ruby script, but IO does the same thing as well. Can anyone explain this topic to me or direct me to a good explanation? I've searched multiple blogs but to no avail.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ARGV` is an array:

```
> ARGV.class
=> Array
```

This array contains the command line arguments for your script. For example:

```
$ cat pancakes.rb 
puts ARGV.inspect

$ ruby pancakes.rb -where is house
["-where", "is", "house"]
```

`IO` is quite a bit different. [IO is](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html):

> [...] the basis for all input and output in Ruby. [...]
>
> Many of the examples in this section use the `File` class, the only standard subclass of `IO`. The two classes are closely associated. Like the `File` class, the Socket library subclasses from `IO` (such as `TCPSocket` or `UDPSocket`).

`IO` is the base class for file-like things in Ruby.

Perhaps you're thinking of [`ARGF`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/ARGF.html) rather than `ARGV`:

> `ARGF` is a stream designed for use in scripts that process files given as command-line arguments or passed in via STDIN.
>
> The arguments passed to your script are stored in the `ARGV` Array, one argument per element. `ARGF` assumes that any arguments that aren't filenames have been removed from `ARGV`.
>
> [...]
>
> If `ARGV` is empty, `ARGF` acts as if it contained `STDIN`, i.e. the data piped to your script.

So you can use `ARGF` like an IO that lets you say:

```
$ your_script some_file
```

and

```
$ some_command | your_script
```

without `your_script` really having to care about which way it is called.

Comment: @Зелёный because they're file-like things

Comment: Thanks! I have a better understanding now.

Answer (score 0):

> The IO class is the basis for all input and output in Ruby. An I/O stream may be duplexed (that is, bidirectional), and so may use more than one native operating system stream.
>
> Many of the examples in this section use the File class, the only
>   standard subclass of IO. The two classes are closely associated. Like
>   the File class, the Socket library subclasses from IO (such as
>   TCPSocket or UDPSocket).
>
> The Kernel#open method can create an IO (or File) object for these
>   types of arguments:
>
> A plain string represents a filename suitable for the underlying
>   operating system. A string starting with "|" indicates a subprocess.
>   The remainder of the string following the "|" is invoked as a process
>   with appropriate input/output channels connected to it. A string equal
>   to "|-" will create another Ruby instance as a subprocess. The IO may
>   be opened with different file modes (read-only, write-only) and
>   encodings for proper conversion. See ::new for these options. See
>   Kernel#open for details of the various command formats described
>   above.

Source: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html

> ARGF is a stream designed for use in scripts that process files given as command-line arguments or 
>   passed in via STDIN.
>
> The arguments passed to your script are stored in the ARGV Array, one
>   argument per element. ARGF assumes that any arguments that aren't
>   filenames have been removed from ARGV.
>
> argv → ARGV Returns the ARGV array, which contains the arguments
>   passed to your script, one per element.

Source: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/ARGF.html